# Firebase SMS OTP says unreviewed, but the app is reviewed and published on google play

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase phone Auth for a flutter app, the app is deployed on the google play and works fine, but when anyone use phone sign in, here is the SMS they receive:

> 123456 is your verification code for com.myapp.myapp (unreviewed)

the app is reviewed and published on google play. I am to sure whats still **(unreviewed)**. can somebody help, please?

Thanks.

Comment: Whats the sms template in firebase?

Comment: %LOGIN_CODE% is your verification code for %APP_NAME%.

Comment: After the review is completed it should display your app name. When did the review complete?

Comment: over a week now.

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: yes, all you have to do is answer the app tasks on your google console, and wait around 7 days to get your app verified. after you finish immediately You should see the status of your app changes from unreviewed to reviewing on the google console dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

all you have to do is answer the app tasks on your google console, and wait around 7 days to get your app verified. after you finish answering the tasks, You should see the status of your app change from unreviewed to reviewing on the google console dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

What happened for me is I filled out all the required information on Google Play then submitted the app for review. After the initial review was done, on the first day the app was on Google Play, the SMS messages were still showing "unreviewed" with the package name. I unlisted the app for a different reason then later that same day I updated the app. The next morning after I set the app from unpublished -> published, I installed the app from Google Play and the SMS code text message no longer showed unreviewed.

Guessing there's a slight delay from when the app releases to when that "unreviewed" status updates.